# Use 'ctrl' for switching keyboard layout in Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

I've been switching keyboard layouts in Windows with Alt+Shift. But I want to do it with a single key only (such as ctrl). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl is usually taken as a modifier, not as a key.

But you may use a macro product like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), to define a macro that translates one of your Ctrl keys to Alt+Shift.

Or it might be easier to use a keyboard-mapping product such as [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html) or [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) :

[image]